# File name in persian ( Farsi ) in assete folder in android

Tags: android, string, compare, filenames, farsi

i want to compare file name in persian ( farsi or arabic ) in assete folder

```
if (filename.matches("*سلام*\\.jpg")) 
{
    copy(getAssets().open(filename), new File(path) );
    items.add(path);
}
```

but i think the android doesn't support asian language !!!
any budy can tell me something about this problem ???

or how i can compare persian( Farsi or arabic ) string in java ( eclips ) !!???

tnx

Answer (score 1):

To me is your regex that is wrong. The following works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String filename = "asdf" + "سلام" + "asdf.jpg";
  System.out.println(filename.matches(".*سلام.*\\.jpg")) ;
}
```

You missed the `.` before the `*`. Not sure if this is a typo, though.

Comment: tnx, but i thing is rooted from supporting utf-8 from android !!! what do you think ?? how i can solve it ?????

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with UTF-8 filenames on Android. Please use [the following code](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/5330018) in your app and post a hexdump of the filenames. Or just test my code and tell what happens

Comment: when i put the file name in English ( like this : (filename.matches(".*4*.\\.jpg")) ) , it worked but when i chenge the '4' to 'سلام' it does'nt worked :( !!!

Comment: How can anybody help you if you keep giving meaningless details? Please, do what I asked. Print a hex dump of the filenames as they are reported to your app and post it. I gave you [the code](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/5330018)

Comment: Also check the encoding of the source .java files (right click on the file in the Projects view > properties)

Comment: your code didn't worked ! something that i want is comparing the filename and a string variable in persian not english, just this !

Comment: The code works. You have to adapt it to use inside your application (for example you won't use the main() method)

Comment: i found this link to solve my problem ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ), but i did'nt know how i can use the  "matches" functon to utf-8 !!!

Comment: :D ! i said "  but i did'nt know how i can ...... "  !!! i think On that link and this link ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ) they explain how we can use " regular expression " in persian or arabic , tnx for helping